# PnP Site Provisioning Documentation

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, pnp-provision

I have successfully saved a Site Template using the following PowerShell command:

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out $templateFile -PersistBrandingFiles -PersistPublishingFiles;
```

I'm looking in the directory that contains the Template.  There is a subfolder that contains Default.aspx, but nothing else.  The PersistBrandingFiles parameter  should save off masterpages, sitelogo, alternate CSS and the files that make up the composed look will be saved, yet they are not there.

I find the documentation to be a bit sparse.  I've searched extensively, but not many examples.  Perhaps I'm completely missing something.

Any suggestions?

Comment: subweb or root web?

Comment: HI Derek.  My Template originates from a Root Web. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the detailed explain of PnP Provisioning PowerShell and example here:

[Getting started with the PnP Provisioning Engine and PnP PowerShell](https://www.erwinmcm.com/getting-started-with-the-pnp-provisioning-engine-and-pnp-powershell/)